# ReCaptcha NoCaptcha shows always additional verification for Firefox

Tags: recaptcha

Why Google ReCaptcha V2 always shows additional verification (pictures) in firefox after clicking "I'm not a robot"?

It is really annoying for users. Especially that Google says, that NoCaptcha is more userfriendly.

Is there any way to skip 2nd level verification?

Demo site: https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/demo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From reCAPTCHA dashboard, you can change the **Security Preference** in **Advanced Settings** section to **Easiest for users**. Try that and see if it works.

[image]

Comment: That's great. How could I omit "Advanced Settings". Thank you!